# SwiftUI Expandable list implementation problem

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list

I'm new to developing iOS apps in Swift and for my second app I chose to-do list.
I use SwiftUI with CoreData in order to store app's data on device.
CoreData stores one entity which is **ITEM** and it has **title**, **fullDescription**, **day**, **date**, **finished** attributes. I want to present all my items (tasks) in expandable list where list categories are the days of the week.

Everything is in one file ContentView for now but later I will make MVVM for the whole project.

I get the following error next to my body var definition:

> Failed to produce diagnostic for expression; please submit a bug report (https://swift.org/contributing/#reporting-bugs) and include the project

Which does not help me identify problem at all.

My ContentView file:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

let daysOfTheWeek = ["Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday", "Thursday", "Friday", "Saturday", "Sunday"]

let dateRange: ClosedRange<Date> = {
let calendar = Calendar.current
let startComponents = DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 1, day: 1)
let endComponents = DateComponents(year: 2021, month: 12, day: 31, hour: 23, minute: 59, second: 59)
return calendar.date(from:startComponents)!
    ...
    calendar.date(from:endComponents)!
}()

struct ContentView: View {
@Environment(\.managedObjectContext) private var viewContext
@AppStorage("isDarkMode") private var darkMode = false
@State var showAddFormView = false

@FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Item.title, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
private var items: FetchedResults<Item>

var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        let screenWidth = geometry.size.width
        let screenHeight = geometry.size.height
        let categories = groupItems()
        
        if showAddFormView {
            AddTaskView()
        } else {
            VStack {
                TopView()
                    .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.1)
                    .padding(.top, screenHeight * 0.025)
                
                NavigationView {
                    List(categories, children: \.items) { row in
                        ForEach(row.items!) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(newItem: item)) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(item.title!)")
                                        .font(.system(size: screenWidth * 0.05))
                                        .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.6, height: screenHeight * 0.04, alignment: .leading)
                                    
                                    if item.finished == true {
                                        Circle().foregroundColor(.green)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.2, height: screenHeight * 0.035)
                                    } else {
                                        Circle().foregroundColor(.red)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.2, height: screenHeight * 0.035)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.9, height: screenHeight * 0.055, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.3, height: screenHeight * 0.05)
                    
                    Button(action: { showAddFormView = true }) {
                        Label("Add Task", systemImage: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .preferredColorScheme(darkMode ? .dark : .light)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, darkMode ? .dark : .light)
        }
    }
}

struct Category: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let name: String
    let items: [Item]?
}

private func groupItems() -> [Category] {
    var categories: [Category] = []
    var itemsForEachCategory: [Item] = []
    
    for day in daysOfTheWeek {
        for item in items {
            if item.day! == daysOfTheWeek[0] {
                itemsForEachCategory.append(item)
            }
        }
        categories.append(Category(name: day, items: itemsForEachCategory))
        
    }
    
    return categories
}

private func saveContext() {
    do {
        try viewContext.save()
    } catch {
        let nsError = error as NSError
        fatalError("Unresolved error \(nsError), \(nsError.userInfo)")
    }
}

private func deleteItems(offsets: IndexSet) {
    withAnimation {
        offsets.map { items[$0] }.forEach(viewContext.delete)

        saveContext()
    }
}
}
```

The problem disappears when I'm not using expandable list and the body var in ContentView looks like this:

```
var body: some View {
    GeometryReader { geometry in
        let screenWidth = geometry.size.width
        let screenHeight = geometry.size.height
        let categories = groupItems()
        
        if showAddFormView {
            AddTaskView()
        } else {
            VStack {
                TopView()
                    .frame(width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight * 0.1)
                    .padding(.top, screenHeight * 0.025)
                
                NavigationView {
                    List {
                        ForEach(items) { item in
                            NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(newItem: item)) {
                                HStack {
                                    Text("\(item.title!)")
                                        .font(.system(size: screenWidth * 0.05))
                                        .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.6, height: screenHeight * 0.04, alignment: .leading)
                                    
                                    if item.finished == true {
                                        Circle().foregroundColor(.green)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.2, height: screenHeight * 0.035)
                                    } else {
                                        Circle().foregroundColor(.red)
                                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.2, height: screenHeight * 0.035)
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.9, height: screenHeight * 0.055, alignment: .center)
                        }
                        .onDelete(perform: deleteItems)
                    }
                    .navigationBarHidden(true)
                }
                
                ZStack {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25, style: .continuous)
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .frame(width: screenWidth * 0.3, height: screenHeight * 0.05)
                    
                    Button(action: { showAddFormView = true }) {
                        Label("Add Task", systemImage: "plus")
                            .foregroundColor(.white)
                    }
                }
            }
            .preferredColorScheme(darkMode ? .dark : .light)
            .environment(\.colorScheme, darkMode ? .dark : .light)
        }
    }
}
```

And then my app preview looks like this (no categories which should be days of the week of course):

[image]

I will be thankful for the help and every advice you could give me because as I said I started my adventure with Swift not long ago.